# How do I capture footage with a Fushicai USBTV007 (EasyCAP)?

Tags: usb, vlc

I am missing the option "**Video4Linux2**" in VLC. I'm still very much a noob at using Ubuntu, so I really don't know why this option isn't showing up. I have looked around the web for hours trying to figure out a solution. When I was looking I found this page 
https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap 
but to be honest I'm confused on whats it telling me to do.

Other info that might help:

OS: **Ubuntu 17.04**

So this is what I got under the terminal when I enter this command: **lsusb**

**Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1b71:3002 Fushicai USBTV007 Video Grabber [EasyCAP]**

Its being detected at least... just not showing up in VLC.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is the newest model in the EasyCap family, the **[Fushicai USBTV007](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap#USBTV007_EasyCAP)** and, according to the linked document, it should have native support both for video and audio capture in the kernel since version 3.19.

Comment: Oh ok, would you how to set up so I could record with then?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same device and it works just fine on Ubuntu 16.04.

Just open VLC and go to

```
Media -> Capture Device
```

Select 'Direct Show' and try out the devices that are listed for audio or video. In my case the name is `/dev/video1/` if you click on play and press play on your camera you should see the movie in your player.

You might also be interesting in reading this: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-webcam-with-vlc/